# Create a Matrix3d matrix that transforms a vector3d around a cone

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I'm trying to make a distributed recursive ray tracer.  I have a Vector3d object (that represents perfect / ideal reflections), and I want to create a random transformation on it so that I get new vectors that are offset from the original vector by an angle.

Sort of like this:
[image]

I think the right approach is to somehow project the vector to the X-axis, rotate along the y axis by the random angle, then rotate along the x axis, and do the inverse projection.  I'm not sure what the matrices would be for these transformations.

(Basically, I want to create the same matrix as OpenGL's glRotated(), without manually entering in the gigantic formula for each element of the matrix)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled across [Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), which may offer a simpler way of calculating the matrix. Wikipedia says it eliminates the need for the matrix exponent which sounds impressive.

Three other methods are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle_representation#Relationship_to_other_representations). The one using quaternions appears to have the advantage (?) of the fewest symbols.